# Why is the interpreter not giving SyntaxError for underscore?

Tags: python

Why python interpreter returns `<class 'type of the variable'>` for `type(_)`.

Why the interpreter is not showing an error message for `_` but in the case of other special characters it is giving `SyntaxError`.

```
>>> type(_)
<class 'type'>

>>> type($)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Python interpreter, `_` always takes the output of the last provided expression as value.

```
>>> 1
1
>>> _
1
>>> 'foo'
'foo'
>>> _
'foo'
```

Note that `_` is not a special character in the sense that whether in the interpreter or not, it is a valid variable name.